# Java frame trouble

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances

I need help with my program because I'll want to put a password and username to my program, so if the username is test && password is 12345 my program will appear a new frame but unfortunately my second didn't work for my label, button and etc here is my code so far.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SwapFields extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwapFields frameTabel = new SwapFields();
    }

    JButton blogin = new JButton("Login");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField txuser = new JTextField(15);
    JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(15);
    JLabel lab = new JLabel("Username :");
    JLabel pas = new JLabel("Password :");
    JLabel cos;
    // JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton y1;
    JButton y2;

    SwapFields() {
        super("Enter Your Account !");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocation(500, 280);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        txuser.setBounds(90, 30, 150, 20);
        pass.setBounds(90, 65, 150, 20);
        blogin.setBounds(110, 100, 80, 20);
        lab.setBounds(15, 28, 150, 20);
        pas.setBounds(15, 63, 150, 20);

        panel.add(lab);
        panel.add(pas);
        panel.add(blogin);
        panel.add(txuser);
        panel.add(pass);

        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        actionlogin();
    }

    public void actionlogin() {
        blogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                String puname = txuser.getText();
                String ppaswd = pass.getText();
                if (puname.equals("test") && ppaswd.equals("12345")) {

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Customer");
                    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setSize(300, 200);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                    cos = new JLabel("Do you have a Customer ?");
                    y1 = new JButton("Yes");
                    y2 = new JButton("No");

                    panel1.setLayout(null);
                    cos.setBounds(70, 30, 150, 20);
                    y1.setBounds(80, 65, 150, 20);
                    y2.setBounds(140, 65, 150, 20);

                    y1.setSize(55, 30);
                    y2.setSize(55, 30);
                    panel1.add(y1);
                    panel1.add(y2);
                    panel1.add(cos);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
                    // this is the code ill change this is the second frame .

                    dispose();
                } else {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Password / Username");
                    txuser.setText("");
                    pass.setText("");
                    txuser.requestFocus();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i am Using JCreator and its version JDK 1.7.0_10

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with _"but unfortunately my second didn't work for my label, button and etc"_?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
    panel.setLayout(null);
```

to

```
    panel.setLayout(new Flowlayout());
```